# Understanding the Repository Pattern

Tags: repository-pattern

Repository pattern is easy to implement, but I am facing a little problem. I am sorry if any feels that my code is long, but when I understand, it worth a lot for me.

I have created a simple interface like following:-

```
public interface IBookRepository
{
    List<Books> GetUsers();
    void Save();
}
```

Following is the class which implement IBookRepository interface

```
public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
{
    private PosContext context;

    public BookRepository(PosContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<Books> GetUsers()
    {
        return context.Book.ToList();
    }
}
```

Following is the BookController:-

```
public class BookController : Controller
{
    #region Private member variables...
    private IBookRepository bookRepository;
    #endregion

    public BookController()
    {
        bookRepository = new BookRepository(new PosContext());
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = (from c in bookRepository.GetUsers()
                     select c).ToList();

        //var userList = from user in userRepository.GetUsers() select user;
        var users = new List<Books>().ToList();

        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View(users);
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading above code:- now my question is on the following line of code

```
private IBookRepository bookRepository;
public BookController()
{
    bookRepository = new BookRepository(new PosContext());
}
```

In above code at first line we write bookRepository is basically a reference of IBookRepository interface (as I read somewhere). why we use this here? if I directly write the following line of below code it also works perfectly.

```
private BookRepository bookRepository;
public BookController()
{
    bookRepository = new BookRepository(new PosContext());
}
```

Please notice in second last code snapshot I use IBookRepository and in the last code shapshort I use just BookRepository  I don't understand the difference of both codes above which has no errors, If anyone please clarify my understanding I shall be highly appreciate and thankful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you noticed is correct. There isn't much use when you structure it like that. You can evolve it like below:

```
private IBookRepository _bookRepository;
public BookController(IBookRepository bookRepository)
{
    _bookRepository = bookRepository;
}
```

Here, the natural question is "Who is passing bookRepository into the constructor?". In .NET, we can use Dependency Injection frameworks like Ninject, Unity etc. to do it.

Dependecy Injection frameworks basically give you the ability to Map interfaces to concrete classes, so that when ever the runtime is looking for an `IBookRepository` an instance of `new BookRepository()` is returned.

What good is that you might ask. The answer is Unit testing. You can then do a Unit test like below. By making our controller dependent on IBookRepository rather than BookRepository we can achieve unit testing. Notice now we can pass any IBookRepository like FakeBookRepository for unit testing.

```
[Test]
public void Index_Passes_Correct_Model_To_View()
{
  //Arrange
  IBookRepository bookRepository = new FakeBookRepository();
  var controller = new BookController(bookRepository);

  //Act
  var result = (ViewResult) controller.Index();

  // Assert
  var listBooks = result.ViewData.Model;
  Assert.Equal(1, listBooks.Count());
}
```

where

```
public class FakeBookRepository : IBookRepository
{
   public List<Books> GetUsers()
   {
       return new List<Book> { new Book() { Id=1 , Name = "abc" } };
   }
}
```